# Initializing the cropper for image uploads

Tags: images, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using wordpress with the ACF plugin.
For a customizable template header I'm using amongst other fields an image field where the user can select the background image of the header. The image needs to have the dimensions of 1600 x 600.
When the user clicks edit on the picture, is there a way to either initialize the cropper to be 1600x600 or at least force it to have those dimensions when the user decides to select the cropped area?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, is there a specific reason why you want to user to crop the image manually? You can edit the ACF-field to specify a specific width and height of the image. Or what I would do is to use a custom thumbnail size and crop the image that way.

Comment: the images used for the header will be handpicked by the authors from free stock image sites. They should also be able to pick the best part of the image to be displayed. We want to leave freedom to the authors but only have the requirement that the image used in the end has the speciffied dimensions.